# How can I estimate the penetration depth of a laser in gallium oxide?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, laser, raman-spectroscopy

I am searching for a way to estimate the penetration depth of a laser with wavelength $\lambda$ in gallium oxide (Ga$_2$O$_3$) in a Raman setup, in order to know the depth at which I am probing. Apparently the Beer-Lambert law can be used (penetration depth $\delta$ is equal to $\alpha^{-1}$, where $\alpha$ is the absorption coefficient), but I have read on another thread that, in case of materials with a low absorption coefficient, this can be problematic. Is that true?

Here is a calculation I did: according to Moss (and also used [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/crat.201000341)), the absorption coefficient of a free carrier can be calculated as follows:

$\alpha(\lambda) = \frac{e^3 \lambda^2 N}{4\pi^2 \epsilon_0 c^3 n m^{*2} \mu_n}$

where $N$ is the free carrier concentration, $n$ is the refractive index, $m^*$ is the carrier effective mass and $\mu_n$ is the carrier mobility. I have those informations for my samples (except for $n$, which I estimated to be 1.9 from the literature), and I get an absorption coefficient:

$\alpha(\lambda = 400$nm$) \approx 0.17$ cm$^{-1}$,

which is in good agreement with the link given above. However using Beer-Lambert law gives me penetration depth of about 6 cm, which is impossible since my samples are about 1 mm thick and I could measure their Raman spectra with a good intensity. Am I missing something? Or is there another way that I could use for estimating the penetration depth of a laser in gallium oxide?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

P.S.: one thing that I find strange is, that the penetration depth decreases with increasing wavelength. But it should be the opposite, shouldn't it?

Comment: The equation you gave shows that the absorption coefficient is proportional to the square of the wavelength, so doesn't that mean that the penetration depth decreases with increasing wavelength? As for the penetration depth of a laser in Ga2O3, since you have a laser and thin Ga2O3 samples, can't you just simply measure the penetration depth yourself using a photodiode laser power meter? Or did you want an independent determination? Measuring the penetration depth yourself has the advantage that it will include any absorption due to impurities that your wide band-gap material might have.

Comment: Thank you @SamuelWeir for your answer. I meant that it decreases indeed, but that the opposite is usually happening (I've corrected it in my original post). Measuring the penetration depth myself is a great suggestion, however I'm in the final days of writing my report and I doubt that I will have access to the samples again. I will take a look at that possibility though. All I need is an approximation really. I find it strange that the absorption coefficient is so low, it feels like another absorption coefficient altogether than what I am used to.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the discrepancy that you are reporting. You say that you get an absorption coefficient of 0.17 cm^-1 but that the Beer-Lambert gives you a penetration depth of 6 cm.  But 1/(0.17 cm^-1)=5.88 cm ≈ 6cm so aren't the two methods consistent with each other, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Well the 6cm that I report have been calculated using the Beer-Lambert law. The discrepancy is that I have been able to obtain perfect spectra out of a sample that is 1mm thick, and no other peak but gallium oxide was detected. To my mind this means that the penetration depth is below 1mm.

Comment: What do your 1 mm thick Ga2O3 samples look like to the eye? Do they look fairly transparent? Do they look more like a material that has a <1mm attenuation length or a 6 cm attenuation length? Since Ga2O3 is an insulator with a 4.9 eV band-gap, a good, pure crystal should appear to be fairly transparent so a 6 cm attenuation length at 400 nm seems to be at least plausible.

Comment: Yes they are quite transparent. Actually it's basically the samples that are presented in the paper that I linked to in my original post, and their characteristics lead to a low absorption coefficient. But if that's plausible, I still don't get why I would not detect the stage on the spectra.

Comment: Don't know but it seems like a 400 nm laser should have no trouble going completely through such thin Ge2O3 samples with very little attenuation.

Comment: Another thing is, that it seems like usually the penetration depth decreases with decreasing wavelength. For example this article (http://www.spectroscopyonline.com/depth-resolution-raman-microscope-optical-limitations-and-sample-characteristics) says (about silicon) "At 633 nm, the wavelength of the HeNe laser, the light will penetrate 3 μm, but this number changes rapidly with wavelength. At 785 nm it is about 12 μm, at 532 nm it is 0.7 μm, and in the UV it can drop to 5–10 nm." It seems surprising to me that we are in a range about 10000 times higher and with a different behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78605/discussion-between-samuel-weir-and-julien).

Comment: @Julien I read quickly through it, I've done raman measurements before and if we want to measure Raman peaks we either put a metal or silicon underneath, preferably a metal such as gold or something similar since the penetration depth of those is usually really low. Oxides are often quite optically transparent, SiO2 is as good as transparent at visible wavelengths, HfO2, TiO2, Al2O3 all are as well and even Ta2O5 is reasonable transparent (about 5 or so dB/cm but that's considered bad in photonics). So this is not a weird number to me from the experience I have working with these materials.

Comment: @Julien check out this paper: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jp311300e
Note fabrication method can change the properties A LOT.